# Unit testing an outgoing query message

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have adapted for Python an example taken from ["The Magic Tricks of Testing" by Sandi Metz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M&t=1229s). Suppose I have this:

```py
class Gear:
    def __init__(self, wheel=Wheel()):
        self.wheel = wheel

    def get_gear_inches(self):
        self._get_ratio() * self.wheel.get_diameter()
```

Now I want to write unit tests for the `get_gear_inches()` method.
In "The Magic Tricks of Testing", Sandi Metz suggests not to set expectations on the return value of `wheel.get_diameter()` (which is an outgoing query), because this would bind us to the implementation, while we only care about the returned results. So we are just supposed to test the returned value, like this:

```py
def test_get_gear_inches():
    gear = Gear()
    assert gear.get_gear_inches() == 12  # For example
```

But I'm a bit confused.

1. Isn't this an integration test? It seems to me like we're testing the behaviour of two components (`Gear` and `Wheel`), not just one.
2. Also, what if this outgoing query (`self.wheel.get_diameter()`) is reaching the db and takes a long time?

**What's the "correct" way to test this?**

---

Note: my alternative would have been to set expectations and mock the behaviour of `Wheel.get_diameter()`, like this:

```py
def test_get_gear_inches():
    wheel_mock = Mock()
    wheel_mock.get_diameter.return_value = 123  # We avoid calling the actual implementation
    gear = Gear(wheel_mock)
    
    assert Gear().get_gear_inches() == 12  # For example
```

But in the video this is discouraged as far as I understand.

Comment: Wouldn't testing `Gear()` also be testing `object.__init__`, `type.__call__`, etc. at that point?

Comment: @MadPhysicist So what would you test, and how? Also: `Gear` is still the "object under test" here, while `Wheel` is a different object.

Comment: Presumably you would be using well-tested types in your implementation. Your unit test is as much of an integration test for `Wheel` as it is for `type` and `object`. In other words, the first method shown is correct: `get_gear_inches` is required to return 12 for the given input no matter how it gets to that number. Your "improved" test does not respect the fact that implementation may change.

Comment: Also, my biggest problem here is having a method called `get_gear_inches`. A much more pythonic way would be to have a property called `diameter_inches` or so (also a property called `diameter` in `Wheel` instead of a method `get_diameter`)

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you. However, this is still not answering all the questions. Besides the fact that `object` is a parent of `Gear`, and should be tested separately (this is not so important anyway). What if `Wheel.get_diameter()` calls an external API and takes a long time?

Comment: The most important thing is to be pragmatic. If you need to mock, mock, and document heavily, so that if the implementation changes, you understand why the regression test broke.

Comment: Also, we would be already testing `Wheel.get_diameter()` in the unit tests of `Wheel`.

Comment: I would agree with the discouragement in the video if all else is equal, but with your example if the query takes a long time. The important thing is to learn context and reasoning skills, not a set of hard and fast rules. If the video does not teach that, it's not a good video.

Answer (score 0):

She is saying that checking `gear.wheel.diameter` is antipattern because this way the test is going to be broken if the implementation of `weel` has changed. But it doesn't bother her that the initialization `weel` already makes the tests more fragile.
But the better solution would be to test `gear` together with `wheel` if this is possible. Or even to test them both together with something bigger.
But if these objects have complex behavior and you want to test them separately then the right solution is to mock `wheel`. Otherwise, you test `wheel` together with `Gear` when there is no such need because you test `wheel somewhere else.
All principles should be applied only in certain situations and shouldn't be applied when it is contrary to common sense. It is not always mentioned by those who teach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have the feeling that we're somehow conflating unit tests and integration tests though. I mean, what are the boundaries of the "unit" you are testing, if you test `Wheel` and `Gear` together?

Comment: The unittest means only that you test one unit. What that one unit is you should decide for each case, it may be function, class, or the whole services, that consists of multiple classes. 
"Unit" doesn't mean that you cannot use a database. For example in Django framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/) unit tests almost always use the database, and it doesn't prevent them to be called unit tests, because the database is considered to be an inherited part of the code